# What happens if you mix old and new style classes in a hierarchy?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

Suppose you have something like

```
class C2: pass
class C1(object): pass
class B2: pass
class B1(C1, C2): pass
class A(B1,B2): pass
```

How does python behave relative to inheritance and method resolution order when you have a mixed hierarchy? Does it obey the old traversal, the new traversal, a mix of the two depending on which branch of the hierarchy is walking?

Comment: woah... apparently people like the question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "a mix of the two".  You can check yourself by using `inspect.getmro()`, which works on both old-style and new-style classes.  It returns the MRO, i.e. the method resolution order.

Any old-style class has a MRO that is depth-first, first-to-last-base.  (This is a bad idea for the most complicated cases, but kept as backward compatibility.)  We can express it like this, which works because the MRO of all parent classes has already been computed:

```
 mro(new_class) = [new_class] + mro(first_base) + mro(second_base) + ...
```

For new-style classes, the algorithm uses the same basic idea, but is more complicated --- it also starts with `[new_class]` but is followed by some more clever merge of the lists `mro(first_base)`, `mro(second_base)`, etc.

Whether each of these base classes are old-style or new-style, they already have their own MRO computed earlier, and these MROs (as lists) are the only thing used to compute the MRO of the new class.

Comment: I should add that `inspect.getmro()` never returns twice the same base class, although it can occur with old-style hierarchies.  That's just a side-effect of using `inspect.getmro()`; the actual MRO in this case really searches several times in the same base classes.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/):

> the linearization of C is the sum of C plus the merge of the
>   linearizations of the parents and the list of the parents.

That would mean that it depends on which branch of the hierarchy it is currently walking (i.e. it's a mix).

It has to be done recursively so I would not expect different behaviour.